# Can Windows Server 2016 EC2 mount EFS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server-2016

I am new to AWS. I have seen numerous definitive answers saying Windows and AWS EFS can't work with each other. Is it still the case with Windows Server 2016?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes they can but it's some work.

Amazon clearly states that EFS + Windows is not supported. But that doesn't mean it isn't possible. CITI @ University of Michigan made an NFSv4.1 client for Windows several years ago.

To use it with AWS EFS you have to comment out one definition so that it always uses `OPEN4_SHARE_DENY_NONE` for the share-deny value – AWS specifically states in its [Unsupported Features page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/nfs4-unsupported-features.html) as disallowing any other value.

And then compile, sign and install. It's not a trivial process, but it's doable. I'm running EFS + Windows Server 2012 R2 on EC2.

More detail in an answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46625030/137641

Comment: How did you achieve EFS on windows server? Can you please share the document to configure EFS on windows server 2019? It would be thankful.

Answer (score 14):

Amazon now supports a fully managed native Microsoft Windows file system,look at Amazon FSx for Windows File Server

https://aws.amazon.com/fsx/windows/

Answer (score 2):

I did this the other way around, by using Samba to provide the Windows share, from Linux.

- Create an AWS EC2 instance.
- Mount the EFS on the EC2 instance (using mount point IP, ensure same security group)
- Install Samba on EC2 instance
- Create local Samba config entry for EC2 local mount point
- Add security group inbound entry for "SMB" port for client IP.
- Mount EC2 samba share on Windows

After that, I could successfully mount the EFS volume on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

No. Windows servers cannot currently (as at June 2017) mount Amazon EFS volumes.

(I don't know if it will be available in future, but I inserted the date because it might be introduced in future.)

Comment: Thank you John. Is it because of technical difficulties, or Microsoft intentionally wants it this way, or Amazon intentionally wants it this way?

Comment: Amazon EFS uses NFSv4, which is not compatible with the Windows SMB sharing model. I heard somebody mention that v3 could work with Windows, but not v4. I guess it comes down to having the right drivers.

Comment: It's not supported, but possible. EFS supports NFSv4 and NFSv4.1. There's a NFSv4.1 client that the University of Michigan put out 5-9 years ago that can be made to work. I've added an answer with more details