# Shared storage mount on AWS Windows EC2?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

i just ask for opportunities to mount a shared storage in Windows Server 2016 or higher.

So i found a lot of on AWS EFS, EBS, S3

My problem is to install data of a Software in a shared volume.

- EBS is just for local mounting, can i map it on other servers?
- EFS ist not for Windows but my favourite choice, are the solutions to mount it as volume in Windows or i should mount it on Linux first?
- Is S3 mountable to use it like a file system?

What can i use or what is the best solution für shared storing data using cloud technologies

Comment: You can now use AWS FSx instead of EFS for windows: https://aws.amazon.com/fsx/

Answer (score 1):

> EBS is just for local mounting, can i map it on other servers?

Indeed, you can mount EBS only to a single EC2 instance. However - you can expose the mounted EBS as NFS on the instance

> EFS ist not for Windows but my favourite choice, are the solutions to mount it as volume in Windows or i should mount it on Linux first?

<del>I don't think that matters.. (if I'm mistaken, please correct me)</del>

Edit: I stay corrected, [AWS EFS from Windows Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956130/aws-efs-from-windows-server-2012) seem you mouting EFS on Windows doesn't work properly. You could mount the EFS on a linux server and expose it as NFS.

> Is S3 mountable to use it like a file system?

S3 is not indeded to be mounted as a filesystem and it's not montable by default.  If needed, there are 3rd party tools to do that (e.g. fuse-s3fs on linux), but IMHO it's not the most efficient way.

As well there are solutions from AWS (aws storage gateway) to migrate on-premise content to S3 and back.

Mounting S3 as FS I'd consider mounting S3 only when

- the files are created or read, not updated (S3 doesn't support updating part of an object)
- the objects (files) are to be shared by other services or through internet